# Disable Keyguard from Notification CustomContentView

Tags: android, richpush

Our application shows a Notification with a CustomContentView (Rich Notification). The View has multiple actions on it, these Actions will open the main Application. However I am unable to request the Keyguard to be disabled (Show the authentication dialog) when our Application is not opened in the background yet.

I assume as the action doesn't originate from the system itself the Keyguard is not lifted automatically, right?

How do one usually handle such a scenario?